# Does Parallel.ForEach() destroys the threads immediately after execution?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have code block which uses Parallel.ForEach, something like below

```
    public void ReadValuesFromServers()
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(serverList, server => 
        {
           //Some logic
        });
    }
```

I will be calling ReadValuesFromServers() method frequently(every 1 or 2 secs), I understand that Parallel.ForEach() internally uses thread to process the commands. I would like to know whether, the threads which are created by Parallel.ForEach(), will it be destroyed immediately after executing the Parallel.ForEach() or will it be maintained in ThreadPool for next set of execution.

Or is it better to use `List<Task>` in this case?

Comment: More than likely `ReadValuesFromServers` is *IO bound*, in which case you should not be using `Parallel.xxx` at all, and instead be using something that supports the async and await pattern.

Comment: `or will it be maintained in ThreadPool for next set of execution.` This, if it decides it wants them for the pool (which it _likely_ will). You certainly shouldn't _rely_ on them being "destroyed immediately".

Comment: Can I ask _why_ you care? This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem .

Comment: @mjwills - I was curious to know the internal implementation because, I don't want to create additional overhead for the platform to commission and decommission threads every two seconds. If that was the case, I thought to have a separate thread pool to perform this operation

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool) heuristics. If the `ThreadPool` decides that the current number of pooled threads are too many compared to the current demand for work, it will automatically decommission some threads. Otherwise, if there is frequent demand for work to be done, the same threads will be reused over and over again by the `ThreadPool`.

This is the expected behavior if you use the default `ParallelOptions`. But it is also possible to specify a [`ParallelOptions.TaskScheduler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.taskscheduler) different than the [`TaskScheduler.Default`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.default), potentially a custom one, and enforce any kind of thread usage scheme that you can imagine (and you are able to implement).